# Open LAN-hosted website in IE 10 Metro

Tags: lan, windows-8-preview, modern-ui, internet-explorer-10

It appears that IE10's Metro mode blocks connections to servers running on the local network (for example, 192.168.1.x).

I am able to connect to the server from IE 10 in regular desktop mode.

How do I connect to a HTTP server on my LAN from Metro IE10?

Comment: What error are you getting exactly?  This seems like a configuration problem.  There are lots of reasons a local ip address needs to be acessed, for instance for the configuration of a router, I know that Microsoft would not prevent that on WinRT while using the Metro browser.

Comment: @Ramhound: A generic "The page can't be displayed" error.  (FWIW, it looks the same as a DNS error, but I'm typing the IP directly.)  Given that I can switch to the Desktop and IE10 connects to the server just fine, it seems like Microsoft is *deliberately blocking* connections to the local network.  (For example, there are some [hacks](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fiddler/archive/2011/09/14/fiddler-and-windows-8-metro-style-applications-https-and-private-network-capabilities.aspx) to get Fiddler working with Metro IE.)

Answer (score 1):

What you're encountering is by design, you're trying to circumvent IE security hosted on a localized installation of Windows operating system.

But what you're doing is a necessity in a development environment for testing functionality and also for testing the same security issues your browser is "protecting you from".

Microsoft has addressed this predicament via an *unsupprted utility* the way they refuse to support many of their resource kit utilities.

Visit this MSDN Blog post for a better explanation as of this date in 2012 the EnableLoopBackUtility.exe which also has the direct download link if you're ready to get right to it:

**BlogPost**

[http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fiddler/archive/2011/12/10/fiddler-windows-8-apps-enable-loopback-network-isolation-exemption.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20151204091513/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/fiddler/archive/2011/12/10/fiddler-windows-8-apps-enable-loopback-network-isolation-exemption.aspx)

**Direct Download**

https://www.fiddler2.com/dl/EnableLoopbackUtility.exe